# Magento 1.7.0.2 - Image type and information need to be specified for each store view

Tags: php, magento

I have Magento 1.7.0.2 installed and running. When I go to add a new product I am getting the "Image type and information need to be specified for each store view."

**Steps I Have Tried:**

```
1) Navigate to System -> Manage stores 
2) Click one each of your store views, and choose “disable” 
3) Save 
4) Clear all cache 
5) re-enable your store view 
6) clear cache again
```

Did that about 6 times. I also tried adding a store view then doing all those steps again and that didn't work, so I deleted the store view I created since this site only needs one store view.

**Other things I tried.**

```
1) Disable all 3rd Party Extensions
2) Go to Stock Theme
3) Renaming the .htaccess in the media folder.
```

Does anyone have other suggestions on what to try?

**EDIT:** The Browse and Upload buttons weren't showing up as well, and apparently it had nothing to do with the message I am getting. After Nick Darley's help I was able to get the buttons to appear but the message is still there, which I can live with.

Comment: Does it force you to set the image, or is it just a warning on the Images section?

Comment: There is no upload button... I have tried it in Mozilla, Safari and Chrome and each one there is no browse or upload button for the images.

Comment: Upgrade your version of Flash and make sure it isn't disabled. Those buttons are flash-powered.

Comment: I have multiple magento sites and this is the only one I can't see the buttons for.

Comment: Would you be willing to send admin credentials so that I can take a look.

Comment: Sent credentials but have since removed that comment for privacy reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after looking into the issues with the provided credentials I see this error.

[image: file error]

I also looked into your configuration and see that you are running magento in a sub-directory. I see you aren't having any other issues from the looks of it so I would just suggest a quick fix.

Create a new folder in the root called skin and then upload a copy of the adminhtml from your server. After that, that should resolve your issue with it not being able to find the file.

Comment: That did the trick, now do you think this is a better option or do you think that I should just create a symlink? Instead of having two copies of it?

Comment: You could create a symlink if you have SSH access to the server and it has root rights. Otherwise this will work, it just depends on how you want to do it. I would probably, create a symlink instead, but I provided this answer due to the fact I wasn't sure of your skill level.

Comment: I went ahead and created the Symlink and sure enough it works still. Thank you so much for you help. Not sure what I would do if someone didn't respond. Now if I could just get that warning message away.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue in Magento CE 1.9 and all other answers did not work.  I ended up going to skin/adminhtml/default/default/media and changing the permissions for uploader.swf and that worked for me.  Also, make sure you have the latest version of Flash installed for your browser.

Comment: Are you using Magento Shared Hosting on Godaddy?

Answer (score 1):

> "Image type and information need to be specified for each store view."

For those who are getting this error please try change flash setting or run in different browser. It works for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Image type and information need to be specified for each store view:

1. Go to File structure  root/media/ dhl
2. Cut or delete the “dhl” folder from there.
3. Clear cache from Admin Panel and now do upload the images
4. Hope, Its working good.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Magento user manual, before adding images to the Magento Gallery, one must select the store view which it shows on the top left as a dropdown.  That would make perfect sense.

I am running Magento with shared hosting on GoDaddy and I do not see a dropdown for that view although I have found that dropdown in another place.  Are you using Magento Shared Hosting on GoDaddy?  According to http://www.submitdigital.com/questions/magento-1-7-image-upload-issues-help-image-type-and-information-need-to-be-specified-for-each-store-view/ it may be an issue specific to the way it is being installed or hosted.

Answer (score -2):

Check if your internet firewall is not blocking the execution of audio and video files, because it needs to execute the files bellow:

```
/skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/flex.swf
/skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/uploader.swf
/skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/uploaderSingleswf
```

Hope it helps.